# Parameter is undefined in Router.route data

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been making my first Meteor.js project, which is basically a simple blog, and I don't think I understand what's happening inside `Router.route()` correctly.

#### client.js

```
Router.route('/category/:_category', {
  template: 'category',
  layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('categorizedPosts', this.params._category);
  },
  data: {
    posts: Posts.find(),
    // THE LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEM
    category: this.params._category
  }
});
```

This code gives me the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_category' of undefined` at the specified line inside `posts`. Without that line, my route works fine although I lose my `category` data.

From the fact that the route, I know that the line `return Meteor.subscribe('categorizedPosts', this.params._category);`, inside `waitOn()` works fine, which means that it correctly grabs `this.params._category`.

### Solution

I've changed my code a little bit from the answer.

```
data: function() {
  return {
    posts: Posts.find(),
    category: this.params._category
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to this.

```
data:function(){
    var category = this.params._category
    console.log(category)
    return Posts.find()
  }
```

Here we change the `data context` to object into function

Comment: I've just edited my code from your answer, but can I ask why it works within function block? Is that a problem of `this` scope?

Comment: Well yes the problems is on the `this` keyword if we use the `this` keyword inside a function scope it will run or get evaluated when the route its running, if you put the `this` inside an object `this.params` will be no longer exists `this` now will be the template instance, in resume if you put `this` inside a function you will get the `params` if you put `this` inside a object you will get the template instance